# can't write unknown attribute "parent_id", has_one and belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-submit, belongs-to, has-one

i'm using rails 4 and was wondering if anyone could find what's wrong in my code.

I have project model and I created a team model that has a belongs_to - has_one relation with project.

**project model:**

```
class CrmProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :crm_team
```

**team model**

```
class CrmTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :crm_project
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :crm_project
  belongs_to :crm_section
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "User"
  has_many :users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

**When submitting the form to create a new team i get this error:**

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in CrmTeamsController#create
can't write unknown attribute `crm_team_id`
```

**and log from server :**

```
  Parameters: {"crm_team"=>{"crm_project"=>"5", "manager"=>"3", "user_ids"=>["", "2"]}, "co
mmit"=>"Create Crm team"}

  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'email@gmail.com' AND "users"."
id" != 2) LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "crm_teams" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2020-03-1
1 07:29:19.735115"], ["updated_at", "2020-03-11 07:29:19.735115"]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use a has_one relation like this

```rb
has_one :crm_team
```

Rails expects you to add `crm_team_id` to your crm_project, in order to understand which crm_team is related with crm_project object. Adding it going to solve your problem.

In my opinion defining opposite like this much better in logic. Because in future these teams can have multiple projects.

```rb
class CrmProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :crm_team
```

```rb
class CrmTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  ***has_one/has_many(pick one)*** :crm_project
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :crm_project
  belongs_to :crm_section
  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "User"
  has_many :users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

Comment: Hi Semih, thanks for writing. I have change the logic and was trying your way but im still getting the same error. I was thinking it could be related to a wrong order of the attributes in the params but havent found a solution yet